# List Direct Messages using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I recently made a little script that uses `tweepy` module. The problem is I can't get DMs using `api.list_direct_messages()`.
Here's my code:

```
elif choose == '6':
    def dmlist():
        msg = api.list_direct_messages()
        print (msg)
        while True:
            choose6 = input("\n1)Refresh\n2)Return to main menu\n\nq)Quit\n\n[Your Choice]:")
            if choose6 in ['1', '2', 'q']:
                break
        if choose6 == '1':
            dmlist()
        elif choose6 == '2':
            mainmenu()
        elif choose6 == 'q':
            print ("Goodbye!")
    dmlist()
```

I tried different methods, such as using cursors, but it either says `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'something'` or it just shows `[]` instead of text in terminal. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.